# Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.id" is null

Tags: java, hibernate

I've a controller defined like this and getting a NullPointerException Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.id" is null (full stack trace shown in the end)
while processing the form using Hibernate. Since this is first time I'm trying to insert a record, there is no record in the table and hence empty so not sure why it's complaining about this.id is null.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/companyNewRecord")
public class CompanyNewRecordController {

    private CompanyManager mgr;

    public void setUserManager(CompanyManager companyManager) {
        this.mgr = companyManager;
    }

    // display the form
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(ModelAndView mav) {

        mav.setViewName("companyNewRecord");
        mav.addObject("CompanyNewRecordForm", new CompanyNewRecordForm());
        return mav;
    }

    // process the form
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(ModelAndView mav,
            @ModelAttribute("CompanyNewRecordForm") CompanyNewRecordForm CompanyNewRecordForm, BindingResult result)
            throws Exception {

        Company addNewCompany = new Company();
        addNewCompany.setName(CompanyNewRecordForm.getCompanyName());
        addNewCompany.setComment(CompanyNewRecordForm.getComment());
        mgr.saveCompany(addNewCompany);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

Here's my `Company` class inside `com.pending.model`:

```
public class Company implements Serializable{
    
        
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String comment;
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getComment() {
            return comment;
        }
        public void setComment(String comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        
}
```

My `Company.hbm.xml` file is also inside `com.pending.model`

`CompanyManager` interface inside `com.pending.service` is as follows:

```
public interface CompanyManager {
    public void setCompanyDAO(CompanyDAO dao);
    public Company getCompany(Integer id);  
    public void saveCompany(Company company);
}
```

`CompanyDAO` inside `com.pending.dao`

```
public interface CompanyDAO {

    public Company getCompany(Integer id);
    public Company saveCompany(Company company);

}
```

`CompanyDaoHibernate` in `com.pending.dao.hibernate`

```
public class CompanyDAOHibernate extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CompanyDAO {

    @Override
    public Company saveCompany(Company company) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(company);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Company id is: " + company.getId());
        }
        return company;
    }

    @Override
    public Company getCompany(Integer id) {
        Company company = (Company) getHibernateTemplate().get(Company.class, id);
        if (company == null) {
            throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(Company.class, id);
        }
        return company;
    }
```

`CompanyManagerImpl` in `com.pending.service.impl`

```
 public class CompanyManagerImpl implements CompanyManager {
    private CompanyDAO dao;

    public void setCompanyDAO(CompanyDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;

    }

    public void saveCompany(Company company) {
        dao.saveCompany(company);

    }

    public Company getCompany(Integer id) {

        return dao.getCompany(id);
    }

}
```

The XML file is defined inside applicationContext-hibernate.xml as follows along with other xml files (not shown below)

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryCOMPANYDB"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSourceCOMPANYDB" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                
                <value>com/pending/model/Company.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And applicationContex.xml contains the following bean :

```
<bean id="companyManager" parent="txProxyTemplateCOMPANYDB">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="com.pending.service.impl.CompanyManagerImpl">
                <property name="companyDAO">
                    <ref bean="companyDAO" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My SQLServer database table design is as follows:

```
Column Name    Data type   Allow Nuls
id              int        
name            varchar(10)
comment         varchar(50)    checkmarked
```

Where, id is set to primary key

Here's Company.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.pending.model.Company" table="company">
<id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="name" />
<property name="comment" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:267)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:370)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:334)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:665)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.dao.hibernate.CompanyDAOHibernate.saveCompany(CompanyDAOHibernate.java:14)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.service.impl.CompanyManagerImpl.saveCompany(CompanyManagerImpl.java:16)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy64.saveCompany(Unknown Source)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.web.controller.CompanyNewRecordController.process(CompanyNewRecordController.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.security.PasswordExpirationFilter.doFilter(PasswordExpirationFilter.java:201)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:106)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:45)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5280)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4972)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:294)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:59)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:85)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:656)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:649)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:644)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.lambda$saveOrUpdate$15(HibernateTemplate.java:667)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:367)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 117 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 130 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.id" is null
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.model.Company.getId(Company.java:15)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 135 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
```

Comment: please share Company.hbm.xml.

Comment: have you tried after removing "unsaved-value="null"" from hbm.xml?

Comment: I haven't. May I know what problem it might be causing or is it something I shouldn't have defined?

Comment: I just tested by removing `unsaved-value="null` and my app didn't even start and and I saw same errors in my stacktrace. So I put it back.

Comment: Hmm. Do you think I should define ` private int id;` instead of ` private Integer id;`? Just saw your comment was deleted. My above question was created to your comment that was deleted.

Comment: tbh, i am trying to figure out issue. Normally, I prefer to use Long for id to support BigInt in database for id and do not use nsaved-value="null" in my code. So, trying to figure out what is causing this issue.

Comment: Sure, please let me know once you figure out the issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
           <generator class="native">
            <param name="unsaved-value">null</param>
        </generator>
        </id>

please do this changes.

Comment: That changes resulted in same exception as soon as I deployed my app. Basically app didn't start so I reverted my changes.

Answer (score 0):

try adding type to your id property in Company.hbm.xml file like this

```
<id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null" type="java.lang.Integer">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Comment: Adding ` type="java.lang.Integer"` didn't help and I am getting same exception.

Comment: tbh I cant see the problem, what I would do here is to set show-sql to true and set a debug point at `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(company)` in CompanyDaoHibernate class to have more info

Comment: Ok, I set the breakpoint and it shows id as null as shown in the screenshot of eclipse here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47OFe.png
How should I handle this then? id is something that is automatically going to generate as it's a primary key.
And were you referring to change `<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>` to `<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>` when you say set show-sql to true?

Comment: Btw, I added a default value , like this `addNewCompany.setId(1);` just to see if I put a default value in my controller.  And I got this exception:

`[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Hibernate: update company set name=?, comment=? where id=?`

Comment: `[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.pending.model.Company] with identifier [1]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.pending.model.Company#1]`

`[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.pending.model.Company#1]`

Comment: a workaround would be to set a default value in Company constructor to set id = -1 and then use `<id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="-1">
<generator class="native" />
</id>`

Comment: another thing to try using save() instead of saveOrUpdate()

Comment: Am I doing wrong if I'm setting the ID like this `addNewCompany.setId(1)` ? May I know why you suggested to set it as `-1` ?

Comment: because 1 is a valid id value that could be generated by hibernate

Comment: Ok, so even in my testing, I should use `addNewCompany.setId(-1)` then? When I tested with `1`, I got the following `[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated. `

Comment: you can set it as a default value inside Company class so that it you don't have to set it everywhere inside you application

Comment: Something like this `private Integer id = -1;` instead of `private Integer id;` ?

Comment: that would work

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Still wondering about this hurdle which I mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: I don't really know what your code looked like there, but I'd guess that you had a name bigger than 10 characters (which is the definition of name column in DB **varchar(10)** )

Comment: Good catch. I was sending name with 11 characters. So after sending `test` as name, I got this error: `Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'mydatabase.dbo.Company'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.` This is weird because I defined `-1` as id in Company class and again it's confusing me why it's giving me this error despite id having default value.

Comment: can you share github repository of the project ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as it’s on my internal server.

Comment: It started working. My table was not setup for autoincrement and hence I was getting errors.

Comment: happy to hear that :) gl

Comment: Thanks for all of your valuable input.

Comment: It again stopped working with saveOrUpdate() but works fine with save() method of Hibernate which is weird. I did see it worked fine in the morning with saveOrUpdate() but not sure what happened now. I will need saveOrUpdate() while updating I suppose.